# What defines the main class if MANIFEST.MF is not present

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, manifest.mf

There are two options when exporting to JAR in Eclipse: export as runnable JAR and export as JAR.

I understand that the runnable jar contains a MANIFEST.MF file, which defines the Main class to be executed when a jar is executed.

I also understand that non-runnable jars are just libraries of classes, that can be added to the classpath so that code is reused. It contains a manifest file, but there is no defined main class within it.

How is a non-runnable JAR file able to execute if the main class is not defined? What are the pros/cons of having a MANIFEST.MF file that defines the main class? Is one more stable than the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What defines the main class if MANIFEST.MF is not present

If a JAR file doesn't have a "META-INF/MANIFEST.MF" component, then **it is not a JAR file**.  It is just a ZIP file and you cannot use `java -jar ...` with a ZIP file.  (You can include a ZIP file on the classpath, but it is not normally done.)

If a JAR file has a MANIFEST.MF without a `Main-Class` attribute, then is not an *executable* JAR file, and `java -jar ...` will fail.

But (as noted) many JAR files are libraries rather than applications.  For them an entry-point class makes no sense.

---

> How is a non-runnable JAR file able to execute if the main class is not defined?

<sup>(The preferred Java terminology is "executable" rather than "runnable".)</sup>

In that case, `java -jar ...` will fail.  Instead, you can run the application like this:

```
  java -cp <classpath> <other-options> com.example.MyApp.Main <args>
```

where `com.example.MyApp.Main` is a main / entry-point class, and `<classpath>` includes the JAR (or ZIP) file and any other runtime dependencies.

Note that an application JAR file *could* contain more than one entry-point class, and the user can decide which one to use.

---

> What are the pros/cons of having a MANIFEST.MF file that defines the main class?

First of all, if you create a JAR file using the `jar` command, then it **will have a MANIFEST.MF**.  The command won't create a JAR without one.

Also, there are other useful things that you can include in a MANIFEST.MF.  These include digital hashes (for signed JARs) and a `Class-Path` attribute for use when the JAR is launched with `-jar`.  For more details, refer to the [JAR file specification](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/jar/jar.html).

The pros of *having* a `Main-Class` attribute in a JAR file are:

1. It is necessary if you want to use `-jar`.
2. It means that the user doesn't need to *know* (or type) the full name for the entry-point class.

There are no significant cons of having a `Main-Class` attribute.  If the user doesn't use the `java -jar ...` launch method, then any such attribute will be ignored.  But I guess you could say that putting a nonsensical `Main-Class` attribute on a *library* JAR could lead to a naive user getting a misleading error.  This is hair-splitting ...

---

> Is one more stable than the other?

Not directly.

You could argue that *using* `-jar` is more stable because an executable JAR ignores the `CLASSPATH` environment variable and `-cp` arguments on the command line.  But the flipside is that you can't force the user to use `-jar` (or double-click) to launch a command.  And you can get similar stability by providing a shell script or BAT file to launch the application with an appropriate entry-point class name and an appropriate classpath.

---

> I executed a non-runnable jar in Eclipse without the classpath or project files and then I ran it and it worked. It was able to identify the main class and run it from there. my question is: how was it able to identify it?

OK ... that is a different question.

What actually happens here is that the Eclipse project has a bunch of configuration information that includes the *build* dependencies.  These provide a default classpath for the Eclipse launcher.  Then, when you use Eclipse's `run` command without an existing run configuration, Eclipse will search all of the classes in the current project looking for *any* classes with a `public static void main(String[])` method.  If it finds only one such class, it *assumes* that it is the entry-point class, and creates a run configuration for the project / class.  When that config is launched, Eclipse does the equivalent of `java -cp <classpath> <class-name> <args>`.

Notes:

1. This is *Eclipse specific behavior*.  The standard Java tool chain doesn't do anything like this.
2. Eclipse is not using `java -jar` here, and hence the manifest won't be consulted to find the entry-point class.
3. This has been known to break.  For example, I have heard that if you delete the main class and create a new one, the launch config doesn't update, and it gives a JVM launch error when you attempt to "run" it.

Answer (score 3):

A "runnable jar" is a jar file where the manifest file contains instructions allowing the `java` Java runner command to "run" the jar file in a simpler way.

E.g. if a `Foo.jar` file has a `static void main(String[])` method in a class `Bar` in package `com.example`, then you can run the program using:

```
java -cp Foo.jar com.example.Bar
```

If the jar file manifest file contains the following line:

```
Main-Class: com.example.Bar
```

then you can run the jar file i an easier way:

```
java -jar Foo.jar
```

Of course, if there is no class with a `main()` method, then the code in the jar file is not "runnable", and hence is just a library file.

That's really all there is to it.

See e.g. [The Java™ Tutorials - Setting an Application's Entry Point](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html) for more information.